# Looking for the plug-in jQuery parallax

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, parallax

I'm searching for a this jQuery plug-in called Parallax, but i cant seam to find the link anywhere :

Plug-in source: 
http://www.laurentiuswonen.com/jaarverslag2010/assets/js/jquery.parallax.js

Comment: It is entirely possible that it's a piece of code written by that site's owner, specifically for that site.

Comment: If that's a plugin, its built poorly. The source code has global variables all over the place. This is not responsible coding.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure its here if google is right http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking. I created one that hooks into the window.scroll event and moves the divs to the appropriate spot.

https://github.com/eiu165/Parallax/tree/master/src

[working sample](http://projecttrack.apphb.com/content/html/prairie2/index.html)

I have expanded on the original to make it easier to use. mine works **horizontally**.  feel free to use it.

use 
    `var hotSpots = [0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000];` to define the locations of your pages

then class your moving div and give it an *x speed* and a *y speed*
and put elements inside the moving div at an *x position* and *y position* and what frame(page) you want it to show.

```
<div class="parallax"  data-speed-x="0"  data-speed-y="0.8" >
    <div   data-frame-y="220" data-frame-x="200" data-frame="1"  ><img src="./img/moon.png"  /></div>
    <div   data-frame-y="350" data-frame-x="420" data-frame="4" ><img src="./img/sun.png"  /></div>

</div>

<div class="parallax"  data-speed-x="-0.4"  data-speed-y="0.0" >
    <div   data-frame-y="800" data-frame-x="420" data-frame="3" ><img src="./img/tree.png"  /></div>
    <div   data-frame-y="750" data-frame-x="320" data-frame="4" ><img src="./img/tree.png"  /></div> 
</div>
```

it is based off of what I found was based off of this site.
http://f6design.com/projects/parallax-scrolling/